# Query about Excel formula - Function IF(…)

Tags: excel-formula

I want to use the function IF() from Excel in a formula for some Cell, as shown below -

```
=IF(I2="SELL","(C2-F2)*D2","0")
```

Which means I want to see if Cell I2 has text- SELL in it (IF condition true), then I want the cell to have formula as (C2-F2)*D2, else if condition is false, it prints 0.

But trouble is that when condition is true, instead of putting the formula for the text it is putting the string (C2-F2)*D2 as it is in that Cell. What I want is that when condition is true, it should interpret (C2-F2)*D3 as formula in that cell. I tried many things , like -

```
=IF(I2="SELL","=((C2-F2)*D2)","0")
```

or

```
=IF(I2="SELL","=("(C2-F2)*D2)"","0")
```

but without any success.

How can I get it working?

thank you,

-AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
=IF(I2="SELL",(C2-F2)*D2,0)
```

does what i was looking for.

thanks,

-AD